# Using template tag to open link in new window

Tags: java, templates, playframework, templatetags

I am using the following template tag in the Play framework to create an anchor tag:

```
#{a @Application.foo( bar )} foobar #{/a}
```

Does anyone know how this can be modified to open the link in a new page (ie, target="_blank")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about :

```
<a href="@{@Application.foo( bar )}" target="_blank">foobar</a>
```

?

EDIT : this should work

```
#{a @Application.foo( bar ), target:"_blank"} foobar #{/a}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work but I was hoping to keep the template tag as it has a few useful things that default when things go wrong.

Comment: have you tried the map notation : `#{a @Application.foo( bar ), target:"_blank"} foobar #{/a}`

Comment: looking at the [source code](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/templates/FastTags.java) for the `a` tag, it takes the first parameter as an url, then it serialize all the others as they come. SO, the map notation should work

Comment: Excellent - thank you, that did work. Would you mind editing your answer with the map notation before I accept it? (Just so someone else can see it without reading the comments)